# Bug in my Web Api 2 call - GET returns 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api2, restful-url

I am writing a web api 2 method to get all credit cards based on someone being a student. I've written a new web api 2 controller but when I use POSTMAN I always get a 404.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using CrazyCards.Web.Interfaces;

namespace CrazyCards.Web.Areas
{
    public class CreditCardController : ApiController
    {

        private readonly ICreditCardDb _creditCardDb;
        private readonly ICustomerDb _customerDb;

        public CreditCardController(ICreditCardDb creditCardDb, ICustomerDb customerDb)
        {
            _creditCardDb = creditCardDb;
            _customerDb = customerDb;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("test")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Test()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("student/{customerId}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetStudentCreditCards(int customerId)
        {
            var customer =
                  _customerDb.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == customerId);

            if (customer != null && customer.EmploymentStatus == "Student")
            {
                var creditCards = _creditCardDb.CreditCards.Where(x => x.CardName == "Student");
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, creditCards, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
            }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ArrayList(), Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter); 
        }  
    }
}
```

This is my localhost url: http://localhost:30046/api/creditcard/student/1

And a screenshot of postman

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the url to your GetStudentCreditCards will be http://localhost:30046/student/{customerId} (mapped via the         [Route("student/{customerId}")] attribute).

If you've got conventional routing on as well, you'll probably also find it at http://localhost:30046/api/creditcard/?customerId={customerId}  (e.g http://localhost:30046/api/creditcard/?customerId=1 )